# Creating a config file to map model in json format to csv

Tags: python, json, csv

How can I build a config file that has a python model in json format that maps to the csv column name?

My plan is when a json data comes in, it will look into this config file, map the data's field with the config's json field, then get the csv column name. Example as below:

First I have a json as below:

```
{
"id": {
    "type": "integer",
    "format": "int64"
},
"category": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/Category",
    "x-scope": [
        "https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json"
    ]
},
"name": {
    "type": "string",
    "example": "doggie"
},
"photoUrls": {
    "type": "array",
    "xml": {
        "name": "photoUrl",
        "wrapped": true
    },
    "items": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"tags": {
    "type": "array",
    "xml": {
        "name": "tag",
        "wrapped": true
    },
    "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Tag",
        "x-scope": [
            "https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json"
        ]
    }
},
"status": {
    "type": "string",
    "description": "pet status in the store",
    "enum": [
        "available",
        "pending",
        "sold"
    ]
  }
}
```

Then I have csv column name as below:

```
id, category, name, photoUrls, tags, status
```

Now I want a config file which has mapping of this 2 field and probably some settings like delimiter type , etc.

How can I achieve that using python?

Comment: Is the question what would you use? Or do you want code? You normally pay people to do the work for you.

Comment: @AER, i just want to know how we can do it, like examples if available.

Comment: Fair, Stack Overflow guidelines usually ask that you at least attempt it yourself. Do you know Python? I've seen questions like these downvoted out of existence before, that's all.

Comment: @AER , yes i did tried and I know python. Just looking for a better way to implement it :)

Comment: OK! Great, post an attempt then. Strictly you need to have at least tried something. I didn't downvote because I take it you're new-ish.

Comment: It helps us know where to start as well.